# Why there is no leak in Grabkit

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, memory-leaks

[Grabkit](https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit) is a Drop-in iOS component to easily import photos from Facebook, FlickR, Instagram, Picasa

In Grabkit, a GRKXXXQuery is a wrapper that transform a delegate based query to block based query.A GRKXXXGrabber is a block based class that use GRKXXXQuery to grab photos from a cloud service.

Take GRKFlickrXXX for example. GRKFlickrGrabber has a NSMutableArray that stores Queries(in super class GRKServiceGrabber). And in method `albumsOfCurrentUserAtPageIndex:withNumberOfAlbumsPerPage:andCompleteBlock:andErrorBlock:`, a query(GRKFlickrQuery) was created and stored in the NSMutableArray by calling `registerQueryAsLoading:`. The query takes blocks as params and in GRKFlickrQuery these block are stored as instance variables. And there is `self` in these blocks

Simply: GRKFlickrGrabber -> NSMutableArray(_queries) -> GRKFlickrQuery(query) -> block -> GRKFlickrGrabber(self)

So there is a retain cycle here. But when I profile the Grabkit Demo using instruments, there is no leak. Did they use some tricks that break the retian cycle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A retain cycle is only problematic if you expect the Block that has a strong reference to an object to be deallocated during that object's deallocation. If the Block is destroyed for some other reason, before then -- such as after the query has run -- the cycle will be broken.

Comment: in method `albumsOfCurrentUserAtPageIndex:withNumberOfAlbumsPerPage:andCompleteBlock:andErrorBlock:`, does `albumsQuery = nil` release `albumsQuery` ?

Comment: If it's compiled with ARC, yes.

Comment: When I remove `albumsQuery = nil`, it will leak. As block retain and release objects automatically. Why `albumsQuery = nil` is necessary?

Comment: It breaks the retain cycle.

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer of GrabKit.
The "albumsQuery = nil;" is indeed here to make the query being released, and avoid the leak.

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierSimonard && JoshCaswell && AminNegm-Awad  Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

A retain cycle does not neccessarily lead to a leak. It is only a leak, when you expect the objects to be cleaned-up in dealloc (including "automatic" dealloc of ARC). If you clear the block property say at the end of a async request manually, it works fine.